# Get value of input in vb.net webbrowser?

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I have the following input, I want to get it value using vb.net WebBrowser, and then put it into a variable how can i perform that?

```
<input type="hidden" name="loginurl" value="https://example.com?ctoken=KWYZlCrYxt">
```

I'm trying to use this code, but i don't know how to put the value i got into a variable:

```
For Each Element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
                'Depending on how the source code is formatted on the tag, you may also try Element.OuterHTML, Element.InnerText and Element.OuterText in the line below
                If Element.OuterHtml.Contains("name=""loginurl""") Then
                    Element.GetAttribute("value")

                    Dim login = value
                     WebBrowser1.Navigate(login)

                    Exit For
                End If
```

Comment: Do you have any code samples that you can provide others with so that they can more easily assist you with your question?

Comment: One option, Ashley, is to add `runat="server"` and give it an `id`, that is if you are able to modify this code.

Comment: @AshleyIvy - If my answer is not helpful...you can ask doubts I will clarify

Answer (score 1):

Drag and drop webbrowser control and use the following snippet

```
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://example.com?ctoken=KWYZlCrYxt")
```

Here is a good [reference](http://www.itechsociety.com/2010/11/visual-basic-net-simple-web-browser/)

Hope this is useful

Answer (score 0):

I'd say just assign a variable with `Dim attributeValue = Element.GetAttribute("value")`... am I missing something obvious here?

```
For Each Element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
    'Depending on how the source code is formatted on the tag, you may also try Element.OuterHTML, Element.InnerText and Element.OuterText in the line below
    If Element.OuterHtml.Contains("name=""loginurl""") Then
        Dim attributeValue = Element.GetAttribute("value")

        Dim login = value
         WebBrowser1.Navigate(login)

        Exit For
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Dim AllElementes As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All
    For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In AllElementes
        If webpageelement.GetAttribute("name") = "loginurl" Then
            Dim login = webpageelement.GetAttribute("value")
            WebBrowser1.Navigate(login)
        End If
    Next
```

should work.